# How to correctly designate returning via argument reference in Javadocs

Tags: java, javadoc, pass-by-reference

Suppose I have a method `foo` that is defined thus:

```
void foo(MyObject a, MyObject b) {
    a.set(1);
    b.set(2);
}
```

and I might call `foo` like so:

```
MyObject a = new MyObject();
MyObject b = new MyObject();
foo(a, b);
```

So I am "returning" from this function via passing the arguments by reference. **How to I write the Javadocs for this?**

Comment: There is no such thing as "return by reference", because is no "pass by reference" in Java

Comment: This is not a value returned by reference. There is no such thing in Java. Your method has side-effect(s) on the argument(s) passed. Document that.

Comment: Thanks for the unnecessary pedantry. Clearly, I am passing a reference by value, and operating upon that reference for the benefit of the caller. You can now go on with your lives now that I've been corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an example, have a look at the documentation for [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29):

> ...
>
> **Parameters:**
>        `a` - the array into which the elements of this list are to
>               be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of
>               the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.
>
> ...

Comment: Ok, so there's no special way to designate a value returned by reference.

Comment: Nope, not that I know of. I think it would be confusing if you tried to include it in the `@return` annotation, since it is used for ordinary return values.